# jQuery animate() step: cross browser now argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Disclaimer: I'm very new in jQuery animations and this problem sounds so stupid it has to have an easy solution but I can't even find a reference of it existing when searching online.

Disclaimer 2: The code you'll see is not optimised, for now I just need it to work.

So I have this svg and I have to animate some of its components, and that's no problem.

I wrote this piece of code that should work even cross browser, but it doesn't and I know why but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
$('#button_next').bind('click', function(){
    if(!(parseFloat($('#last_rectangle').attr('x')) <= 308.1)){
        $('.activeScroll').each(function(){
            var xValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
            // $(this).attr('x', (xValue - 45 - 85.5));
            $(this).animate(
            {
                x: "-=130.5"
            }, {
                duration: 1000, step: function(now) { $(this).attr('x', now); }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

What this does (and it works in Chrome) is it changes the x value smoothly giving me an eased scrolling. It doesn't work in FF though. It works only if i substitute

```
$(this).attr('x', xValue-now);
```

with

```
$(this).attr('x', now);
```

And I get why when logging the `now` value. In FF it goes from 0 to -130.5 which is not what I want in the first case, in Chrome the same exact code outputs the relative numbers i need so it works like a charm.

For completeness this is what my HTML elements look like:

```
<rect x="177.6" y="12.9" class="activeScroll" width="85.5" height="2"/>
```

and I have multiple `<rect>` elements.

It seems like FF can't work with relative values, although `xValue` gets detected correctly so it can read (and write, as you can see by the commented line, which works cross-browser but it's not animated) the attribute `x`.

The documentation doesn't mention such a difference in `now` so I'm stuck with this problem.

I'm using jQuery 2.1.4, if you think the issue is the version, updating to 3.2.1 gives me the error that I'm setting a property that only has a getter, but it sets itself anyways in jQuery 2.1.4 so I really don't understand where the problem lies there.

Anyone has a clue?